# Is there a way to prevent electricity flow without physical intervention

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, electricity

Is there a way to put an external switch on a lightbulb cable, in order to create an external switch to prevent and allow electricity flow?

Without using any massive electromagnets or the likes...

Comment: Without cutting the cable and interposing something? No.

Comment: Screwing in and out the lightbulb in its socket seems a possibility but you might burn your hand.

Comment: You mean a remote operated switch? Like this? http://www.ebay.com/itm/Remote-Control-E27-10M-Screw-Wireless-Light-Lamp-Bulb-Holder-Cap-Socket-Switch-1-/361854444106?hash=item544034a24a:g:704AAOSwjVVVqJrh

Comment: "without physical intervention" makes it very difficult. Magic?

Comment: The usual method is to plug the lamp into a switched outlet. What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Trying to figure out if there is a solution to this, so far seems impossible... a remote light switch which is easy to install

Comment: I assume "lightbulb cable" refers to some sort of electrical cord.  What exactly are you trying to add a switch to that doesn't already have one?

Comment: I think there may be a language barrier issue here. Generally switching mechanisms don't use electromagnets (relays are the only thing that come to mind). Do you mean you want to switch the current via non-mechanical means? Any solid state solution will work there. If you mean without interfacing the switch with the cable... well, that would be impossible, unless you can do it before or after the cable via your source (before being preferred).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to put an external switch on a lightbulb cable, in order to create an external switch to prevent and allow electricity flow?

Yes.  Look up something called a *light switch*, or sometimes a *wall switch*.  These things are very common and available in hardware stores and many other places.